# How do I create an animation in After Effects for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Currently in the company where I work, they are using Flutter, before I created the animations in After Effects, created a JSON and sent it to the developers. Now, I need to find a way in which After Affects talks to FLUTTER.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [lottie](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie) package. Add your JSON as an asset or host it somewhere. Then you can follow the example code(shown below) to display it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            // Load a Lottie file from your assets
            Lottie.asset('assets/LottieLogo1.json'),

            // Load a Lottie file from a remote url
            Lottie.network(
                'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xvrh/lottie-flutter/master/example/assets/Mobilo/A.json'),

            // Load an animation and its images from a zip file
            Lottie.asset('assets/lottiefiles/angel.zip'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```